# iOS development - alternative to unity3d for basic 3D app

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, 3d

I need to make a simple text/info app that has some simple 3D views, but I cant justify the cost of unity at the moment, and have no experience with Objective C.

Are there any other SDK's that support 3D for iOS that don't require knowledge of Objective C? and have a low cost or ideally free during development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend [cocos3d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/archives/1274), even though it's only a very early version. It's easy to use and open-source (free). You do need some objective C knowledge, but if you have time to run through a couple tutorials, you should be able to produce some nice results with very little effort. [This should help you get started.](http://sree.cc/iphone/how-to-setup-and-build-your-first-cocos3d-hello-world-project)

Comment: That does look interesting, and will definitely look into it at some point. But due to time restraints I will have to consider other ways since I would need a fair bit of objective C to implement all of the non 3d functionality as well.